# Django Class-based views: How to check an object value before returning view

Tags: django, django-views

I have what I imagine is a quite common scenario, yet I didn't find any clear solution to it in my searches.

I have a web app, where most of the objects have a FK relation to a user. For these objects, I want to check that the related user is the same as the self.request.user.

I wrote a mixin that overrides get_object to perform this simple check before returning the object.

Is there a better way? Here I just raise the 404 for example. I'll probably return a specialised message for this in the real code.

```
class CheckObjectUserMixin(object):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None)
        if pk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

        elif slug is not None:
            slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})

        else:
            raise AttributeError(u"Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                                 u"either an object pk or a slug."
                                 % self.__class__.__name__)

        try:
            obj = queryset.get()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_(u"No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                          {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})

        # Until here it was the code from Django's get_object.
        # Now for the CheckObjectUserMixin I perform a simple check. 
        # If the object does not belong to the request user, we want to raise an 404.

        if obj.user_id != self.request.user.id:
            raise Http404(_(u'You do not have permission to view this page'))
        else:
            return obj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is correct the way you have it, but there is no need to copy all Django's `get_object` code.
Instead you can do it like so:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin

class CheckObjectUserMixin(SingleObjectMixin):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(CheckObjectUserMixin, self).get_object(queryset)
        if obj.user_id != self.request.user.id:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```